# Apple mail can't verify certificate

Tags: mail.app, email, security, keychain, certificate

I have set up a local mail server on our NAS to backup mails.

For some time now Apple Mail can't verify the certificate.

I found this Apple help post: https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/trust-a-certificate-mail14058/15.0/mac/12.0

But I don't have any options to approve the certificate. My screen just shows me information about it.

Any suggestions how to approve the certificate?
I already tried to import it into my keychain but didn't help.
[image: certificate]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great. Just one more search away after I posted this (of course I did research before I posted) I found the solution:

In this Apple post: https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/use-personal-certificates-mlhlp1179/mac

It says in the last paragraph to open the keychain and select the certificate to always trust it. That solved the problem.

BUT: The first article I linked in my questions is exactly my problem but the "solution" is misleading and not working because there are no options in the window that shows up in Apple mail.